# jQuery: Checking if next element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to check if a next element exists? Check my code:

```
if($("#people .making-of .mask ul li.current").next("li") != null) {
    alert("Exists");
}
else {
    alert("Dont exists");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Have you tried looking at `.next('li').length`?

Comment: And I thought `next().length` inferred it was looking for an element of the same type, but it seems not, and you have to define the element type again, ie `$("table").next("table").length` to see if a table follows the current table?

Answer (score 26):

Use [`jQuery .is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), using `.is()` you can even check what tag, class or ID next element have?

```
if($("#people .making-of .mask ul li.current").next().is('li')) {
    alert("Exists");
}
else {
    alert("Dont exists");
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The briefest method is just:

```
if( $( ... ).next('li')[0] ) {
```

Since jQuery functions always return a jQuery object, it's never equal to `null`. But accessing a jQuery object like an array acts like you are using an array of DOM objects, so `[0]` will pull the first matched DOM element or `null`. Checking `.length()` against 0 works, as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `length` method in jQuery:

```
if($(...).next().length > 0) {
    alert("Exists.")
} else {
    alert("Doesn't exist!")
}
```

Comment: (You need to use the ``.length`` property.)

Answer (score 3):

```
if($("#people .making-of .mask ul li.current").next("li").length > 0) {
    alert("Exists");
}
else {
    alert("Dont exists");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the post above says, you need to check the length of the item. Jquery.next() will always return a jquery object, but if there is no next item, it will have a length of 0.

```
if($("#people .making-of .mask ul li.current").next("li").length > 0) {
    alert("Exists");
}
else {
    alert("Dont exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good to use like.

```
   if ($(this).nextAll().length > 0) { 

     alert("Exists");

   }else{

     alert("Don't exists");

   }
```