# Identifing if next/previous element exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Checking if next element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678499/jquery-checking-if-next-element-exists)

I'm implementing a custom slider using jquery. There I want to give facility to load next/previous image when user press `right`/`left` keys respectively.

It is working fine but when cursor reach `last`/`first` element, code breaks as it do not find  further elements. My code is as follow:

```
function movePointer(dir){
    var selected = $("#imgslider > ul > li > img.siddslideselected");
    console.log(selected);
    var selectedli = selected.parent();
    if(dir=='left'){
        var nabourele = selectedli.prev()
    }else if(dir=='right'){
        var nabourele = selectedli.next();
    }
    console.log(nabourele);
    if(nabourele){
        selected.removeClass('siddslideselected');
        nabourele.children().addClass('siddslideselected').trigger('click');
    }
}
```

If current position of cursor is in middle, everything work fine but if cursor is on first element, pressing `left` key breaks the code. I try to stop that by checking `if(nabourele){`, but it is not working. console log for `nabourele` show `[]` in that case.

How can I test condition if next/prev element exist or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test the `length` property:

```
if ( nabourele.length )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph. That worked. Thanks for very quick reply too.

Comment: You could also set nabourele (what language is that? :) to `#imgslider > ul > li:first-child > img` or `#imgslider > ul > li:last-child > img` `if (!nabourele.length)` so that the slider loops to the beginning/end.

Comment: @powerbuoy `nabourele=neighbor-element` Sorry to post that but we do not check spelling mistake when code breaks near deadline. Thanks for suggestion. Now when the code is running, I can work to make it better.