# how to stop .next() going off list of li's

Tags: jquery

i am working on a gallery where i navigate previous and next list items using arrow keys. now using `.next()` and `.prev()` i am able to navigate really nice but the problem starts when the last List Item is there and the jquery goes to `.Next()`.

How can i stop  a process that it won't go after last li Item.

i mean the `next()` function dosent apply after last Li.
Here is my sample code

```
  var ul = $('#thumbsList');
ul.find('li').first().addClass('current');
```

This one adds a class.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nextHandler').click(function () {

        var nextListItem = ul.find('li.current').next();

        ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current');
        nextListItem.addClass('current');
        var imagePath = ul.find('li.current').children('img').data("fullsrc");
        // Setting Image Path to Current Next Image path
        $("#fullImagePlaceholder").attr("src", imagePath);


    });
});
```

This does the job.
**But the problem starts when it jumps of the last LI.** How to stop it.
thanks.

Comment: Check `nextListItem` if is null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test if there is a next using `if (nextListItem.length > 0)` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678499/jquery-checking-if-next-element-exists):

```
 var nextListItem = ul.find('li.current').next();

    if (nextListItem.length > 0)
    {
      ul.find('li.current').removeClass('current');
      nextListItem.addClass('current');
      var imagePath = ul.find('li.current').children('img').data("fullsrc");
      // Setting Image Path to Current Next Image path
      $("#fullImagePlaceholder").attr("src", imagePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have this

```
 var nextListItem = ul.find('li.current').next();
```

you may check

```
if (nextListItem.length) {
// .. do the job
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always check with .length is greater than 0 if it still has items. this way you can navigate and find elements in any object.