# How to check if .prev() fails

Tags: jquery

How can I check if `.prev()` fails, ie, if the element has no previous sibling?

Aparently on failure it returns an empty jquery object but each of the following checks for failure return false:

```
alert( ele.prev() === undefined ); // 'false'
alert( $.isEmptyObject( ele.prev() ) ); // 'false'
alert( ele.prev() == $() ); // 'false'
```

*Note* ele does indeed not have any previous siblings

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678499/jquery-checking-if-next-element-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** methods return a `jQuery` object and you can check it contains any element by checking it's **[`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)** property.

```
alert( ele.prev().length == 0 )
```